# Azure Static Web App custom domain with GoDaddy is no working

Tags: azure, blazor-webassembly, godaddy-api, azure-static-web-app

I've a static Blazor website hosted on azure and I've set custom domain for it. The issue is custom domain https://www.raohammas.site/ is working while root domain [https://raohammas.site/](http://raohammas.site/) doesn't work. Why? Though, I've added required DNS records for my domain.

**DNS RECORDS On GoDaddy**

[image: DNS RECORDS]

**Azure Custom Domains**
[image: Azure domain status]

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/custom-domain-external) guide by Microsoft to setup everything.

Comment: have you followed the guide for apex domains? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/apex-domain-external

Comment: @silent Hey thanks. i read this doc and it turns out GoDaddy doesn't support alias and root domain setup like some other providers do. Instead i used domain forwarding to forward https://raohammas.site/ to https://www.raohammas.site/ .

Comment: @silent if you wanna answer this then I'll accept your answer else i would answer it myself and will close this question.

Comment: Sure, done. Glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow the guide how to set up Apex domains: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/apex-domain-external